# Cropping and placing image to achieve battery level effect

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimage, cgrect

I am trying to achieve the battery level effect by drawing on a plain battery image another cropped image based on current battery level.

At the moment I am able to change the colour of the empty battery image but I don't know how to crop, the new one, and place it on top of the original.

I've found some useful links on how to crop but, every single of them, is cropping from top-left corner of the image. I would like to have as a starting point the bottom-left and set the height according to current level.

In addition, it is possible to combine or place the cropped image on top of the original?

Here is my original image.

[image]

...and what I am trying to achieve

[image]

At the moment I am trying this code,

```
int width = emptyBm.size.width;
int height = fullBm.size.height * level / 100;

UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"battery_icon"];
UIImage *image2 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"battery_icon_full"];

CGRect rect = CGRectMake(0, image.size.height-height, width, height);
CGImageRef imageRef = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect([image2 CGImage], rect);

CGImageRef actualMask = CGImageMaskCreate(CGImageGetWidth([image CGImage]),
                                              CGImageGetHeight([image CGImage]),
                                              CGImageGetBitsPerComponent([image CGImage]),
                                              CGImageGetBitsPerPixel([image CGImage]),
                                              CGImageGetBytesPerRow([image CGImage]),
                                              CGImageGetDataProvider([image CGImage]), NULL, false);
CGImageRef masked = CGImageCreateWithMask(imageRef, actualMask);

batteryBackground.image = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:masked];
```

However, because I am using `CGImageCreateWithImageInRect` the cropped part is **stretched**

Comment: Well starting from the bottom left corner means starting from the images height value minus the "height" of the used part. It's just simple math defining your CGRect.

Comment: Well I actually realized what shadowhorst was saying after posting my example code. It's enough to re-calculate the CGRect by substracting the used part if your green battery image already has the shape and transparency. Just don't forget to set it's contentMode to a non-stretching one. The example I described also should be usable but non-optimal unless you want to use a plain-green rectangle as fill indicator.

Answer (score 2):

Use the gray battery image as mask. Create a green rectangle and apply the mask you created. Here is a link to iOS masking: [link](http://www.abdus.me/ios-programming-tips/how-to-mask-image-in-ios-an-image-masking-technique/)

**EDIT:**
I hope this works (not tested):

```
int width = emptyBm.size.width;
int height = fullBm.size.height * level / 100;

UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"battery_icon"];
UIImage *image2 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"battery_icon_full"];

// For clarity, just pretend the mask method I gave link to you is defined in your class.
UIImage *maskedImage = [self maskImage:image2 withMask:image];

// I assume the two imageviews are already connected to outlets.
self.backgroundImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];
self.foregroundImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:maskedImage];

// Make it's image stick to bottom so it won't stretch.
self.foregroundImageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeBottom;

// Then calculate the frame again to reflect changes of battery status.
CGRect rect = self.backgroundImageView.frame;
rect.size.height = height;
// Push the masked imageview a to bottom as amount of missing battery height.
rect.origin.y = rect.origin.y + self.backgroundImageView.frame.size.height - height;
self.foregroundImageView.frame = rect;
```

Comment: I have worked out the solution with a way similar to this! Thank you. :)